# Need help with Bluetooth component for TinyCircuit

Tags: bluetooth

I am looking to get some assistance to learn how to program the Bluetooth module for TinyCircuits.

I am currently using the [UARTPassThrough.ino example](https://github.com/TinyCircuits/TinyCircuits-TinyShield-BLE-ASD2116/tree/master/examples/STBLE/examples/UARTPassThrough) to try and learn BlueNRG's functions.

I see that in the UARTPassThrough.ino code, the loop() function calls the aci_loop() function in UART.ino. I'm not too sure what are ACI commands. What does the aci_loop() function do for its Bluetooth functionality?

```
void aci_loop() {
  HCI_Process();
  ble_connection_state = connected;
  if (set_connectable) {
    setConnectable();
    set_connectable = 0;
  }
  if (HCI_Queue_Empty()) {
    //Enter_LP_Sleep_Mode();
  }
}
```

Also, when I try to use the aci_gap_start_general_discovery_proc() function, the value returned is 255. What does the value 255 mean?

Main .ino file:

```
void setup() {
  SerialMonitorInterface.begin(9600);
  while (!SerialMonitorInterface); //This line will block until a serial monitor is opened with TinyScreen+!
  BLEsetup();
}

void loop() {
  aci_loop(); //Process any ACI commands or events from the NRF8001- main BLE handler, must run often. Keep main loop short.
  BLEdiscoverymode();
}
```

Added own function to UART.ino file:

```
void BLEdiscoverymode() {
  uint8_t output;
  output = aci_gap_start_general_discovery_proc(0x4000, 0x4000, 0x00, 0x01);
  PRINTF("--Bluetooth function return value: %d--\n", output);
}
```

Output from Serial Monitor

```
03:44:21.572 -> --Bluetooth function return value: 255--
03:44:23.774 -> --Bluetooth function return value: 255--
03:44:25.989 -> --Bluetooth function return value: 255--
03:44:28.208 -> --Bluetooth function return value: 255--
03:44:30.407 -> --Bluetooth function return value: 255--
```

Help would be much appreciated.

My TinyCircuit uses these components:

- [TINYZERO PROCESSOR BOARD](https://tinycircuits.com/collections/processors/products/tinyzero-processor)
- TINYSCREEN OLED TINYSHIELD
- [BLUETOOTH LOW ENERGY TINYSHIELD](https://tinycircuits.com/collections/communication/products/bluetooth-low-energy-tinyshield) (ST)
  (Uses the BlueNRG-MS chipset with the SPBTLE-RF module)
- Lithium Ion Polymer battery - 3.7V 150MAH

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one

Comment: You may be better off asking the authors through a [github issue](https://github.com/TinyCircuits/TinyCircuits-TinyShield-BLE-ASD2116/issues) since they are far more likely to know what this does than we do (since this is some unknown third party board and library and not something many other Arduino users even know exists, let alone have a clue how to use).